# How to set loglevel in slapd.d?

Tags: openldap

I have set up openLDAP 2.4 on Debian 11, and I want to change a few parameters, like the loglevel and logfile, which appears to be really simple:

```
# man slapd.conf
SLAPD.CONF(5)                                                       File Formats Manual                                                      SLAPD.CONF(5)

NAME
       slapd.conf - configuration file for slapd, the stand-alone LDAP daemon

SYNOPSIS
       /etc/ldap/slapd.conf

DESCRIPTION
       The  file /etc/ldap/slapd.conf contains configuration information for the slapd(8) daemon.  This configuration file is also used by the SLAPD tools
       slapacl(8), slapadd(8), slapauth(8), slapcat(8), slapdn(8), slapindex(8), and slaptest(8).
...
       logfile <filename>
              Specify a file for recording debug log messages. By default these messages only go to stderr and are not recorded anywhere else.  Specifying
              a logfile copies messages to both stderr and the logfile.

       loglevel <integer> [...]
              Specify  the level at which debugging statements and operation statistics should be syslogged (currently logged to the syslogd(8) LOG_LOCAL4
              facility).  They must be considered subsystems rather than increasingly verbose log levels.  Some messages with higher priority  are  logged
...
```

except that there is no file called `slapd.conf`; it has been replaced by `/etc/ldap/slapd.d`, which is much tidier. However, I don't find a description of how the `slapd.conf` parameters fit into `/etc/ldap/slapd.d`; there is a parameter called `olcLogLevel` in `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` that may well the one, but how about everything else from `slapd.conf`?

Anyway, my question: how can I change the loglevel and logfile in the new scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `slapd-config(5)` manual page. Nearly all settings retain the same names in the LDAP configuration backend, only with the `olc` namespace prefix. (And you're really supposed to edit these via LDAP or at least via `slapmodify`, not by hand.)

```
       olcLogFile: <filename>
              Specify a file for recording slapd debug messages. By default these  mes‐
              sages  only  go  to stderr, are not recorded anywhere else, and are unre‐
              lated to messages exposed by  the  olcLogLevel  configuration  parameter.
              Specifying a logfile copies messages to both stderr and the logfile.

       olcLogFileFormat: debug | syslog-utc | syslog-localtime
              Specify  the prefix format for messages written to the logfile. The debug

       [...]

       olcLogLevel: <integer> [...]
              Specify the level at which debugging statements and operation  statistics
              should be syslogged (currently logged to the syslogd(8) LOG_LOCAL4 facil‐
```